# Jquery: detach() parent without affecting children... unwrap() does too much

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to specifically detach() a parent div while leaving children intact.

unwrap() would work perfectly for me however it removes the div and I will want to reinstate it later on. Is there a unwrap() method for detach?

Example:
css:

```
body{
   background: green;
}

#parent{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: black;
}

#red{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="yellow">yellow</div>
        <div id="red">red</div>  
    </div>   

</body>
```

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#yellow").click(function(){
          one();
    });

    $("#red").click(function(){
        two();
    });

});

function one(){

    $("#yellow").unwrap();  
}

function two(){

        $("#parent").appendTo("body");
        $("#yellow").appendTo("#parent");
        $("#red").appendTo("#parent"); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UzvCR/1/

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it...

First, create a clone of the parent element using [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and empty out the contents using [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Next use [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to take out the parent.

Finally, use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap the clone.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/UzvCR/2/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //clone the parent and empty out the content
   var clone = $('#parent').clone().empty();

    $("#yellow").click(function(){
          one();
    });

    $("#red").click(function(){
        two();
    });

    function one(){
        //unwraps #parent
        $("#yellow").unwrap();  
    }

    function two(){
        //use .wrapAll
        //perhaps use a class for each child element -- $('.color')
        //so you don't have to use multiple IDs in the selector -- $('#red, #blue, #yellow')
       $("#yellow, #red").wrapAll(clone);
    }  
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions!